# How to get property from TopoJSON file using D3.js version 7?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

**====== UPDATE: ======**

as Andrew commented, to get the the value **codarea** it's simple as using **d.properties.codarea** just like the following:

```
.style("fill", function(d){
    return colorScale(d.properties.codarea);
})
```

**=== END OF UPDATE ===**

I have the following TopoJSON file:

```
{
    "type":"Topology",
    "arcs":[...],
    "transform":{
        "scale":[...],
        "translate":[...]
    },
    "objects":{
        "BRGR":{
            "type":"GeometryCollection",
            "geometries":[
                {
                "arcs":[[0,1,2]],
                "type":"Polygon",
                "properties":{
                    "codarea":"1"
                }
            },
            {
                "arcs":[[[3,4,5,-1]],[[6]]],
                "type":"MultiPolygon",
                "properties":{
                    "codarea":"2"
                }
            },
            {
                "arcs":[[[-5,7,8,9]],[[10]]],
                "type":"MultiPolygon",
                "properties":{
                    "codarea":"3"
                }
            },
            {
                "arcs":[[11,12,-9]],
                "type":"Polygon",
                "properties":{
                    "codarea":"4"
                }
            },
            {
                "arcs":[[-13,13,-2,-6,-10]],
                "type":"Polygon",
                "properties":{
                    "codarea":"5"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to log it in the console using:

```
console.log(topology.objects.BRGR);
```

Having the following expected result:

```
{type: 'GeometryCollection', geometries: Array(5)}
  geometries: Array(5)
    0: {arcs: Array(1), type: 'Polygon', properties: {…}}
    1: {arcs: Array(2), type: 'MultiPolygon', properties: {…}}
    2: {arcs: Array(2), type: 'MultiPolygon', properties: {…}}
    3: {arcs: Array(1), type: 'Polygon', properties: {…}}
    4: {arcs: Array(1), type: 'Polygon', properties: {…}}
    length: 5
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
    type: "GeometryCollection"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
```

I'm unable to log the value of **codarea** directly. What brought me the closest solution was:

```
console.log(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.BRGR).features);
```

I've tried a lot of possibilities such as:

```
console.log(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.BRGR).features.properties.codarea);
```

without success. I have no idea what we have to do to get this value.
Actually I'd like to use it in a D3.js script to modify the color of the map on the fly.
The code is:

```
// svg general properties
var width = 1024,
    height = 512;

// set projection
// https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#projections
var projection = geo.geoCylindricalEqualArea() // projeção cilíndrica equivalente de Lambert
    .parallel(32)
    .scale(670)
    .rotate([45,14,0]);

// color scheme
var colorScheme = d3.schemeBlues[5];
colorScheme.unshift("#eeeeee")
var colorScale = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range(colorScheme);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

var g = svg.append("g");

// load and display the map
d3.json("map.json").then(function(topology) {

    g.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.BRGR).features)
        .enter().append("path")

//---->
//----> THIS IS WHERE CODAREA WOULD MODIFY COLOR
//---->
        .style("fill", function (event, d) {
            // pull data for this state
            d.codarea = ???;
            // set the color
            return colorScale(d.codarea);
        })

        .attr("d", path)
});
```

And the highlighted part I extracted from http://bl.ocks.org/palewire/d2906de347a160f38bc0b7ca57721328 but differently from the source I'm using D3 version 7

```
//----> MY CODE
//----> THIS IS WHERE CODAREA WOULD MODIFY COLOR
//---->
        .style("fill", function (event, d) {
            // pull data for this state
            d.codarea = ???;
            // set the color
            return colorScale(d.codarea);
        })
```

And here the original code:

```
   .attr("fill", function (d){
        // Pull data for this country
        d.total = data.get(d.id) || 0;
        // Set the color
        return colorScale(d.total);
    })
```

But as I said, I can't get the proper data from my TopoJSON. How would this be possible, so I can use it in the script?

Comment: try using: `colorScale(d.properties.codarea)`.

Comment: That did the job! Thanks! Now I'm struggling how to load two external files to the code. In previous versions it was with promisse.all or d3.queue, but in version 7 when I use one of them I receive the notice that promisse or queue are not functions...